# Use JsonIgnore for an attribute in an other class

Tags: java, json, stack-overflow

I meet an issue with a class contained in a library that I use.

This issue comes when I want deserialize it.

Indeed, this class has a method names "getCopy" which returns a new instance of himself which contains this same method and call it still a `StackOverFlowException` on the following cycle :

> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166)
>
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
>
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:723)

```
public class Object {
   ...
   ObjectAttribute objectAttribute;
   ...

   public ObjectAttribute getObjectAttribute(){
      return this.objectAttribute
   }
   ...
}

public class ObjectAttribute{
   ...

   public ObjectAttribute getCopy{
      return copy(this) //return a new instance of himself
   }
   ...
}
```

Is there a way to ignore the method `getCopy()` like `@JsonIgnoreAttribute("objectProperty.copy")`?

Comment: Methods of the class are not being serialized, only fields are. If you are getting StackOverflowError then there must be a problem with the way you are trying to serialize/deserialize data. Provide more code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply !
I'm not sure that "get" method are not call during serialization...
I don't know what can I show you more.
If I put a break point in my methode I can see that at each iteration, this method is called.

Comment: I guess You are trying to SERIALIZE an object.  And you can`t annotate this method by  @JsonIgnore, as it 3-rd party class?

Comment: Correct it's my problem. Else this 3rd Class should be serializable.

Answer (score 2):

For this specific use case, when you have a class in a third party library that you are not able to modify, Jackson provides the [Mix-in annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

The idea behind this concept is to provide a class that indicates how the serialization of another class should be accomplished.

For instance, consider the following mix-in class definition for your use case:

```java
public abstract class ObjectAttributeMixIn{
   // You need to provide definitions for every property you need
   // to serialize, and the proper constructor if necessary
   ...

   // Ignore the getCopy method
   @JsonIgnore
   public abstract ObjectAttribute getCopy();

   ...
}
```

You can use the full set of Jackson annotations in the mix-in definitions.

Then, associate the mix-in with the `ObjectAttribute` class. You can use the instance of `ObjectMapper` you are using for serialization for this purpose:

```java
objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(ObjectAttribute.class, ObjectAttributeMixIn.class);
```

Yon can also register a custom module instead; please, see the [relevant documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations#how-does-it-work).

Answer (score 1):

for ignore method `getCopy`, just enough rename this method , e.g `copy`

every method start with `get` then serialized ,e.g if method name is `getSomething` then serialized to `something: (return value by method))`

so if you change method name to `copy` or `copyInstance` or every name without start by `get` then method not serialized

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The problem is that my Class is in an other lib, I haven't access to the source code. Else sure, I can change the name of my method or add @JSonIgnor on it but I can't in my case...

Answer (score 1):

You can override [JsonSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672721/jackson-ignore-attribute-on-sub-class-that-is-3d-party) and do specific logic for class

> ```
> public class CustomSerializerForC extends JsonSerializer<C> {
>    @Override
>    public Class<C> handledType() {
>        return C.class;
>    }
>   @Override
>    public void serialize(C c, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
>        String upperCase = c.getValue().toUpperCase();
>        jsonGenerator.writeString(upperCase);
>    }
> }
> ```

And use `Serializer` in moudle used in `ObjectMapper`:

> ```
>    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyCustomModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
>    module.addSerializer(new CustomSerializerForC());
>    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
>    mapper.registerModule(module);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can register serializer and choose the fields you would like

```
 /**
 * We can not change source code so we are adding serializer for a specific type.
 *
 */
public static class JsonSpecificTypeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<SpecificType> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(SpecificType t, JsonGenerator jsonGen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGen.writeStartObject();
        jsonGen.writeFieldName("field1");
        jsonGen.writeNumber(t.getield1());
        .......

        jsonGen.writeEndObject();
    }

}

/**
 * Customize jackson.
 *
 * adding configuration to jackson without overriding spring boot default conf.
 */
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customizeJackson() {
    return jacksonObjectMapperBuilder -> {
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.serializerByType(SpecificType.class,
                new JsonSpecificTypeSerializer());
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways I see how to figure out your issue:

1. Write custom deserializer for you specific class and register it in Jackson mapper.
2. Tune up global Jackson mapper to ignore class getters in auto-detection and use only fields.

Please try 2 way with following config:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

If you decide to move forward with 1 way, please write here if you need help.